# Transmission not reloading after reboot

Tags: raspbmc

I'm wondering whether any of you good people can help me, I'm attempting to set up transmission on a pi running raspbmc. I've got it all set up, everything seems fine but after a reboot it doesn't seem to load up the customised settings.json file. When I SSH in and reload the transmission-daemon service it works fine, but once rebooted attempting to access it from the LAN gives a "cannot access page" error.

Settings.json:

```
    {
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127,
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020,
    "alt-speed-up": 50,
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::",
    "blocklist-enabled": false,
    "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist",
    "cache-size-mb": 4,
    "dht-enabled": true,
    "download-dir": "/media/750Gb/Torrents/Complete",
    "download-limit": 100,
    "download-limit-enabled": 0,
    "download-queue-enabled": true,
    "download-queue-size": 5,
    "encryption": 1,
    "idle-seeding-limit": 30,
    "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false,
    "incomplete-dir": "/media/750GB/Torrents/Incomplete",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true,
    "lpd-enabled": false,
    "max-peers-global": 200,
    "message-level": 2,
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
    "peer-limit-global": 240,
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 60,
    "peer-port": 51413,
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535,
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152,
    "peer-port-random-on-start": false,
    "peer-socket-tos": "default",
    "pex-enabled": true,
    "port-forwarding-enabled": false,
    "preallocation": 1,
    "prefetch-enabled": 1,
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true,
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30,
    "ratio-limit": 2,
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
    "rename-partial-files": true,
    "rpc-authentication-required": true,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-password": "{3504b7903448a88d97be15eff59d4b1080281a7dFLIGnnJ3",
    "rpc-port": 9091,
    "rpc-url": "/transmission/",
    "rpc-username": "pi",
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "seed-queue-size": 10,
    "speed-limit-down": 100,
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false,
    "speed-limit-up": 100,
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false,
    "start-added-torrents": true,
    "trash-original-torrent-files": false,
    "umask": 18,
    "upload-limit": 100,
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0,
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
    "utp-enabled": true
}
```

I assume something must be wrong, but I've reinstalled twice now following two different guides and nothing doing, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.
Cheers for the help.

Update:
Here is the init.d script for transmission-daemon:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          transmission-daemon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start or stop the transmission-daemon.
### END INIT INFO

NAME=transmission-daemon
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
USER=debian-transmission
STOP_TIMEOUT=30

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/sbin"

[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0

[ -e /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

start_daemon () {
    if [ $ENABLE_DAEMON != 1 ]; then
        log_progress_msg "(disabled)"
        log_end_msg 255 || true
    else    
        start-stop-daemon --start \
        --chuid $USER \
        $START_STOP_OPTIONS \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $OPTIONS || log_end_msg $?
        log_end_msg 0
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting bittorrent daemon" "$NAME"
        start_daemon
        ;;
    stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping bittorrent daemon" "$NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet \
            --exec $DAEMON --retry $STOP_TIMEOUT \
            --oknodo || log_end_msg $?
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
    reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading bittorrent daemon" "$NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet \
            --exec $DAEMON \
            --oknodo --signal 1 || log_end_msg $?
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting bittorrent daemon" "$NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet \
            --exec $DAEMON --retry $STOP_TIMEOUT \
            --oknodo || log_end_msg $?
        start_daemon
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}" || true
        exit 2
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess problem is because your transmission daemon tries to start before network is ready.

Try to change its init script to make it start last.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would I change on there?

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with init scripts so I can see what is wrong in them?

Comment: If you start it from `/etc/rc.local` and you are using ethernet, it should be okay.  If you are using wifi, you might want to incorporate a delay or a test, but make sure that is forked.  If this is the problem, really whoever packaged transmission for debian should have thought of it.

Comment: I've updated with the script, I run over ethernet so theoretically it should be fine. Could it be an issue with the start user? I can't see why that would mean it works when restarted but not rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

I did have to swap

```
# Required-Start:    remote_fs syslog
# Required-Stop:     remote_fs syslog
```

with

```
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
```

to make it work.

finally it boots the web gui.

Comment: Consider turning this answer into a comment.

Comment: I agree that this does not seem like an independent answer but I am not  sure what it is a comment on, because it could apply to the original question or either of the current answers -- but I suspect it is really an elaboration of [this one](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24763/5538), and might as well stand. For future reference, wova, we're not a discussion forum (post are not statically ordered in time), and you should try and present answers as such if you are posting. E.g., "To elaborate on ___'s suggestion...". Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Many people are facing with the same issue. It's an issue with transmission-daemon itself. I too faced this issue and created a workaround by reloading the transmission-daemon 20 seconds after boot.

If you want the workaround,

Create a file in /etc/init.d using

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-reload
```

Write/Copy the following code into the file

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          transmission-reload
# Required-Start:    remote_fs syslog
# Required-Stop:     remote_fs syslog
# Should-Start:      portmap
# Should-Stop:       portmap
# X-Start-Before:    nis
# X-Stop-After:      nis
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Reloads transmission-daemon
# Description:       Modify sleep according to your preferences
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO
sleep 20
sudo service transmission-daemon reload
```

Save the file by pressing **Ctrl + O** and then press **Enter Key**. Exit nano using **Ctrl + X**.

Make the file executable using

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/transmission-reload
```

Now, add the file to rc.d using

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/transmission-reload defaults
```

Transmission's Web Interface should now load automatically after each boot

Comment: I tried this and I get `insserv: Service remote_fs has to be enabled to start service transmission-reload
insserv: Service syslog has to be enabled to start service transmission-reload
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header` when I run `sudo update-rc.d transmission-reload defaults`

Comment: Don't use `sudo` in init scripts.  They're run with privileges by default.