# automatically restart service on boot

Tags: raspbmc, cron, services

I'm still suffering from the problems I described in [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24762/transmission-not-reloading-after-reboot), and since I can't find a solution I've come up with a workaround. I'm thinking if I can use cron to schedule a restart of the transmission-daemon service on reboot then it will automatically load up the correct settings.json file and solve the issue. I can write the cron script, but I don't even know how I would go about writing the script that cron would call to get transmission-daemon to restart. If anyone has done anything similar or could point me in the direction of a tutorial that explains it I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Try `sudo grep transmission /var/log/*` to see if it has indicated any problems there.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the crontab of root:

`@reboot /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon restart`

But I would still recommend to do it "the right way", with the command

`sudo update-rc.d transmission-daemon defaults`

More details in the Debian documentation: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

Comment: I'd already tried the right way, it didn't make a difference. Either way, the crontab command you wrote has fixed the problem so thanks :)

Comment: Actually it didn't, it worked for a couple of restarts but has now stopped again. No idea why.

Comment: Can you find anything useful in `/var/log`?
`sudo grep -r transmission /var/log` might give you a clue.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at, but it stopped working when I restarted with a torrent downloading. I can't see anything obvious at the time that it stopped working. Any idea what I'd be looking for?

Comment: No, not really. At this point it isn't Raspberry Pi specific so I would suggest that you head over to either Askubuntu or Unix&Linux, two other StackOverflow sites with a lot more Linux users.
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to do an ugly workaround by just changing the @reboot to @hourly. Unfortunately this means it pauses any torrents that are queued but I'll just keep an eye on it. Thanks for your help anyway.